# performance of Polygon Collider 2D

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm developing a 2D isometric game. I, want to put `PolygonCollider2D` of each individual diamond-shaped tiles to get a touch input on an individual tile.

What is the use of such excessive `PolygonCollider2D` impact on performance? Or there a better approach?

[image]

Comment: This looks like a 3D Mdeol to me. Is this a 3D Model?

Comment: no, it's bunch of 2d sprites.